# Recovering an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

How can one recover an analytic function $L(\gamma)$ in real line, knowing its values only on two infinite sequences 
$\{\lambda_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ and $\{\mu_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$?

$\lambda_n = \pi n, \mu_n=\cfrac{\pi}{2} + \pi n, \; n \in \mathbb{Z}$

$L(\lambda_n)=a_n$, $\; L(\mu_n)=b_n$, $n=0, 1, 2, \ldots$ .

Comment: I don't see what it helps to have two such sequences.

Comment: Indeed...for instance, picking $\mu_i = \lambda_i$ shows that if it's possible, then having ONE sequence is enough.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, since you could just add $\sin(-\alpha_1 + \pi n)\sin(-\alpha_2 + \pi n)$ however many times you want to get a new function.

Comment: If the sequence $\lambda_n$ tended to some limit in $U$, where the analytic function is defined on domain $U$, then by the Identity Theorem, you know the value of the analytic function on all of $U$.

Comment: Unfortunately, here $\lambda_n \to \infty$ and, thus, the Identity Theorem doesn't work.
@PatrickStevens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been noted, there is no uniqueness here.  But you can get **an** analytic function with these values.  For convenience, put the two sequences together into one sequence of distinct complex numbers $\alpha_n$, $n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$, where you want
$L(\alpha_n) = \beta_n$, such that $|\alpha_n| \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.
Let $f_n$ be a polynomial such that 
$$\eqalign{f_n(\alpha_n) &= \beta_n - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} f_j(\alpha_n)\cr
f_n(\alpha_j) &= 0 \ \text{for}\ j < n\cr
|f_n(z)| &< 2^{-n}\ \text{for}\ |z| < |\alpha_n|/2 \cr}$$
and take
$$ f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(z) $$
a series that converges absolutely, uniformly on compact sets, so the 
sum is analytic on all of $\mathbb C$.

For example, you could take $f_n$ of the form

$$f_n(z) = \left(\frac{z}{\alpha_n}\right)^M \left(\beta_n - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} f_j(\alpha_n)\right)  \prod_{j=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{z - \alpha_j}{\alpha_n - \alpha_j}$$

where the factor $(z/\alpha_n)^M$ is omitted if $\alpha_n$ happens to be $0$; otherwise $M$ is an integer with
$$M > n + \log_2 \left| \beta_n - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} f_j(\alpha_n)\right| + \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \log_2 \left(\frac{|\alpha_j| + |\alpha_n|/2}{|\alpha_n - \alpha_j|}\right)$$

Comment: I've found a book related to this question.
If you are interested take a look:
Levin B.Ya. - "Lectures on entire functions" (AMS, 1996)(T)(ISBN 0821802828)(242s) 
Lectures 20-22.